# jquery get sender's form field value onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with lots of forms on it and every form has a dropdown and two buttons - ok and decline. I have an onclick that will trigger a function:

```
<input type="button" value="decline" 
       class="submit_button_wow" 
       onclick="submit_decision({{ x.id }},false,this)">
```

how do I figure the selected dropdown value from this form inside submit_decision?

> {{x.id}}

is the id of decision that I fill out via template engine.

Comment: I've gone as far as $(sender).parent("form") in my bugzilla debugger - but can't figure the rest of it :)

Comment: within submit_decision I just need to know the selected value - I then form a URL and do $.ajax with it to pass it down my restful services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refrence the form from the button's `form` property.  Then get the drop down list by its name.

```
function submit_decision(decision, myBool, button) {
    var dropdown = button.form.myDropdown;
    var selectedValue = $(dropdown).val();
}
```

Comment: thanks, I keep taking js as somewhat much more complicated than it really is :)

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a reference to button to the `submit_decision` (the `this`). From it you can get parent form and, subsequently, the dropdown and its value.

Try something like this:

```
$(sender).parent("form").find("select").first().val()
```

Comment: yes, I figured that I could do $(sender).parent("form") but can't figure how do move further.